# How can I set the ‘SecureCustomProperties’ property in the ‘Property Table’ of an MSI using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-deployment

There is a known bug that will makes "MSI built on Visual Studio installs into C: instead of C:\Program Files" in Windows Vista and 7 if  'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 1.

The workaround and issue is explained [in an MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2011/12/21/msi-built-on-visual-studio-installs-into-quot-c-quot-instead-of-quot-c-program-files-quot.aspx?Redirected=true). The fix is to "add TARGETDIR to ‘SecureCustomProperties’ property in the ‘Property Table’". All nice - but how can I do that? I'm aware this isn't much of a programming question but none the less took me a lot of futile time searching the web so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a great many bugs in Visual Studio Deployment Projects.  So many that Microsoft is removing it from the next release of Visual Studio and providing free access to InstallShield Limited Edition instead.

The will find to "fix" Msi's built by VDPROJ people will generally write utilities that run as postbuild commands that perform SQL updates on the MSI to massage the table data.

pseudocode follows...

```
select Value from Property where Property.Property = "SecureCustomProperties"

strings.split ";" into collection

if collection not contains "TARGETDIR" add "TARGETDIR" to collection

collection serialize using ; to string

update Property set Value = newstring where Property.Property = "SecureCustomProperties"
```

Comment: So to sum your answer up: Does not work in VS and has to be done manually, right?

Comment: Not manually, ( it can be scripted as a post build event ) but it certainly has to be done outside of the tool.

Comment: If you start to outgrow that ISLE google "Augmenting InstallShield" and read a few of my blog articles for ideas on how to extend it's capabilities.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into using WiX instead.  You'll never have a problem with a high-level toolkit preventing you from changing MSI tables exactly how you want again.

Comment: I've found some edge cases where the same could be said about WiX.  XML/XSD is also a high level abstraction of the underlying relational database and some gaps exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ORCA and then change the property table as follows:

[image]

Comment: @0X0nosugar the issue was fixed meanwhile